# Is possible to sort a views field that is generated by custom views handler?

Tags: 7, views

I have a view field that is generated by a views handler.
The logic inside the render method is as following:

```
function render($class) {

  if (class_hasnt_started($class)) return 'Registered';

  if (user_completed_entire_course($class)) return 'Completed';

  if (user_completed_some_classes($class)) return 'Attended x of y';

}
```

My question is, can such a field be sorted?

Answer (score 0):

For a Table display, use the style options to make the field sortable.[image]